# How can I configure my application launcher (.desktop file) or my script so that GNOME distinguishes the started application?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, .desktop

I have created two `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

These have different `Name`, `Icon` and `Exec`. But `Exec` points to scripts which both start the same binary (in different versions).

This was working fine in Unity, but GNOME seems not to differentiate these two applications.

The consequence is: When one application launcher is started and still running, I cannot start the other one. GNOME switches to the started (wrong) one.

> How can I configure my .desktop file or my script so that GNOME distinguishes the started application?

Here are the used files:

eclipse-neon.desktop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=EclipseNeon
Icon=eclipse-neon
Exec=/home/witek/bin/eclipse-neon.bsh
Comment=Eclipse Neon
```

eclipse-neon.bsh:

```
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=
export SWT_GTK3=0
/opt/eclipse-neon/eclipse
```

eclipse-mars.desktop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=EclipseMars
Icon=eclipse-mars
Exec=/home/witek/bin/eclipse-mars.bsh
Comment=Eclipse Mars
```

eclipse-mars.bsh:

```
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=
export SWT_GTK3=0
/opt/eclipse-mars/eclipse
```

Comment: Probably an example with two different desktop files would be better.